# list value wont show on spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

My spinner allows me to choose the array list and is able to use onItemSelected method but the chosen value does not display in the spinner

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/reasonspin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

My words will show when I change background color of spinner to black which means my text is white but changing the textcolor to black has no effect

Answer (score 0):

Just check with your text colour and background colour of the view maybe the text colour is same as your background colour.